# Getting ARCore camera rotation in degrees in from camera pose

Tags: dart, arcore, euler-angles

I am trying to convert camera rotation from quaternion to euler angles but I get really weird results. While rotating with y-axis values go from 0-90-0, and 0-(-90)-0.
I don't understand if there is a way to change this to 0-360 values?
For converting quaternion in eulers angels I am using this code ([origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975109/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-quaternions-and-get-the-same-euler-angles-back-fr)):

```
Flutter/dart code:

vector.Vector4 rotationQuat;

double x,y,z,w;
double roll, pitch, yaw;
x = rotationQuat.x;
y = rotationQuat.y;
z = rotationQuat.z;
w = rotationQuat.w;

double t0, t1, t2, t3, t4;
t0 = 2.0 * (w*x + y*z);
t1 = 1.0 - 2.0 * (x*x + y*y);
roll = atan2(t0, t1);

t2 = 2.0 * (w*y - z*x);
t2 = t2 > 1.0 ? 1.0 : t2;
t2 = t2 < -1.0 ? -1.0 : t2;
pitch = asin(t2);

t3 = 2.0 * (w*z + x*y);
t4 = 1.0 - 2.0 * (y*y + z*z);
yaw = atan2(t3, t4);

eulerAngles = vector.Vector3(roll, pitch, yaw);
```